# Stop ScheduledExecutorService after it runs two times?

Tags: java

I'm trying to have some code to be executed only 2 times with a delay of 500 microseconds between each execution.

So far I have used the `ScheduledExecutorService` and an `int counter` to track how may times the `ExecutorService` has run my code, but I want know if this is a good approach and if there is better way:

```
private void dingdong() {

    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        int count;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            count++;

            //TODO operation

            if (count == 2) {
                exec.shutdownNow();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `ExecutorService` is overkill. If you just use a normal Thread, it can run your operation, sleep, and run it again.

```
new Thread(() -> {
    doTheThing();
    TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(500);
    doTheThing();
}).start();
```

Comment: Your solution is indeed much simplere.